# How to draw picture like this using Python?

Tags: python, frontend, python-imaging-library, data-visualization

I am working on a project which scrapes steam sales data and generate an infographic based on the data I scraped. I have finished data scraping part including the pictures and is now working on the infographic.
The scraped data looks like this:

```
[Neon Chrome,-71%,¥ 14,86.79%,4 days, Neon Chrome is a cyberpunk-themed twin-stick shooter video game played from a top-down perspective. The player takes control of remote controlled human clones and is tasked with eliminating the Overseer to stop their oppressive regime on the dystopic society.]

[Crossing Souls,-75%,¥ 12,78.79%,1 day,11 hours ago,1 year ago,1,331690, Crossing Souls is a inventive thrill ride that embraces clever, varied gameplay and heartfelt storytelling to coalesce into a gem of a game.]
```

Ideally i want to reorganize the texts and generate infographic from scratch like this (some info are just for showcase):

[image]

However, I really do not know how to generate such a picture using python or other automated methods. I found several libraries like pillow which have basic apis like import picture, draw lines and texts, but it cannot handle the layout proply since my infographic could have multiple number of cards, and the text's length may varies, so I cannot hardcode the text or image to appear at (x,y) positions.

Comment: You want to show steam's sale banner?

Comment: Can you share what you have currently, and what you want to achieve ? I wasn't clear to me. I assume you want to stack different pictures vertically correct ?

Comment: Hi vin, sorry for the confusion, I have updated the queston